# Nest.js with AWS Cognito, How to get access to the user attributes

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, amazon-cognito

I have created the **Nest.js** app. And I use **AWS Cognito** to manage user authentication and authorization. I use **amazon-cognito-identity-js** for handling user signin/signout and **@nestjs/passport** /  **@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))** for validating tokens and user access for the routes.
Now I need to get access to the current user attributes(email, phone_number...) in other routes of the app. What is the best way to do this?

auth.service.ts

```
import { AuthConfig } from './auth.config';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUserAttribute,
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private userPool: CognitoUserPool;
  private sessionUserAttributes: {};
  constructor(private readonly authConfig: AuthConfig) {
    this.userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
      UserPoolId: this.authConfig.userPoolId,
      ClientId: this.authConfig.clientId,
    });
  }
  registerUser(registerRequest: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }) {
    const { name, email, password } = registerRequest;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return this.userPool.signUp(
        name,
        password,
        [new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'email', Value: email })],
        null,
        (err, result) => {
          if (!result) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(result.user);
          }
        },
      );
    });
  }

  authenticateUser(user: { name: string; password: string }) {
    const { name, password } = user;
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: name,
      Password: password,
    });
    const userData = {
      Username: name,
      Pool: this.userPool,
    };

    const newUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return newUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: (result) => {
          resolve(result);
        },
        onFailure: (err) => {
          reject(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }
}
```

jwt.strategi.ts

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';
import { AuthConfig } from './auth.config';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private authConfig: AuthConfig,
  ) {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `${authConfig.authority}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: authConfig.clientId,
      issuer: authConfig.authority,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  public async validate(payload: any) {
    return !!payload.sub;
  }
}
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards, Header } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use AccessToken for API auth. How can I verify Cognito AccessToken? This only works for IdToken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`user`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/v0.5.0/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L243) is set as a property on the request when passport successfully authenticates the user.

The [request can be injected](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#login-route) in your controller and user property then accessed.

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards, Header, Request } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  getHello(@Request() req): string {
    console.log(req.user);
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Comment:   thank you, sir!

just don’t forget to return the user object from the validate fun

`export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
 ....
  public async validate(payload: any) {
    return payload;
  }
}`

Comment: Feel free to update the answer.